# Density map with latitude and longitude

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to plot a joinplot like below to see where is the most arrived point in regard to frequency.
[image]

I tried to calculate the density of my data. (Latitude and Longitude)

```
m1 = df['Latitude'].values
m2 = df['Longitude'].values

m1 = df['Latitude'].values
X = m1.reshape(-1, 1)
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1).fit(X)
x = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100).reshape(-1, 1)
density_x = np.exp(kde.score_samples(x))
plt.plot(x, density_x)
plt.show()

m2 = df['Longitude'].values
Y = m2.reshape(-1, 1)
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1).fit(Y)
y = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), 100).reshape(-1, 1)
density_y = np.exp(kde.score_samples(y))
plt.plot(y, density_y)
plt.show()

density = {'Latitude':density_x, 'Longitude':density_y}
density = pd.DataFrame(density)
density.head()

with sns.axes_style('white'):
plot = sns.jointplot(x='Latitude', y='Longitude', data=density, kind="kde", space=0.7)
```

In the end, I always get an error:
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py:1077: UserWarning: Dataset has 0 variance; skipping density estimate.

I don't understand. Can anyone help me figure it out?